# Can't copy/move files with space at end of file name

Tags: c#, winapi, filenames

It's really crazy! I have created a file using Far 2.0 (http://www.farmanager.com/, maybe you can use some other file manager); its filename is 'C:\123.txt ' **(yes, with space at the end of filepath)**.

And I'm trying to copy or move this file using a C# program:

```
File.Copy("C:\\123.txt ", "C:\\456.txt", true);
```

But it fails with the "Could not find file 'C:\123.txt '." exception. But the file exists!

I'm trying the Windows API:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern int MoveFile(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName);
MoveFile("C:\\123.txt ", "C:\\456.txt",);
```

But it fails too.

And I'm trying the xcopy utility:

```
C:\>xcopy "C:\123.txt " "C:\456.txt" /Y
File not found - 123.txt
0 File(s) copied
```

How can I can rename the file programmatically? And why does this happen?

My OS: Windows 7 x64

Comment: What if you use `@"""C:\123.txt """`?

Comment: How did you create that file? Normally whitespace is truncated.

Comment: zerkms, Illegal characters in path.

Comment: If you have short filename generation enabled, you can do a `dir /x` to see the short name (usually with a `~` in it) and use that to rename it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a character in your filename that's illegal in Win32. To circumvent the Win32 path parser, you just have to prefix your filename with `\\?\`. For example:

```
MoveFile(@"\\?\C:\123.txt ", "C:\\456.txt");
```

This technique will also allow you to have paths up to 32k in length (you only get 260 including the drive letter in Win32).

Comment: That worked for me, but FindFirstFile/FindNextFile is not returning the space for me.

Comment: @malkia: If you're having a problem with invalid filenames, you can always use the 8.3 short name if it's available.

Comment: In my case I can't, as I disabled the 8.3 support. Having 8.3 might slow down NTFS in case of lots of file in the same directory (the slow down is due to trying to find 8.3 name that is not reused). I was wrong about FindFirstFile/Next - it works fine. Later GetFullPathName removed the space. Now it's working all good :) (I even thought UNICODE functions were required - DeleteFileW, but that was not the case)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the file with a illegal character after the space

```
C:\123.txt :illegal
```

The : and everything afterwards will be removed but the space will remain. You can also create files ending with a space this way.