# I can't move/rename a directory with space at its end

Tags: c#, directory

I have a large directory of folders and files that contain a space at the end of the name, I'm trying to rename the directories with that space to one without, so that another application would be able to access it.

I'm using C# (but if there's a better option that would fix that issue please suggest) and here's my entire code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace removing_spaces_in_directories_names
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string path = "../../../old_directory";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            WalkDirectoryTree(di);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
        {
            if (root.Name != "old_directory")
            { renameDirectory(root); }
            DirectoryInfo[] diArr = root.GetDirectories();
            foreach(DirectoryInfo di in diArr)
            {
                WalkDirectoryTree(di);
            }
        }

        static void renameDirectory(System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("renaming: " + dir.FullName);
            string newName = ReplaceLastOccurrence(dir.FullName, " ", "");
            if (Directory.Exists(dir.FullName) == false)
            {
                //dir.MoveTo(newName);
                String oldName = @"\\?\"+dir.FullName;
                Directory.Move(oldName,newName);
            }
        }

        public static string ReplaceLastOccurrence(string Source, string Find, string Replace)
        {
            int place = Source.LastIndexOf(Find);

            if (place == -1)
                return Source;

            string result = Source.Remove(place, Find.Length).Insert(place, Replace);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding "\?\" to the beginning of the folder name as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274886/cant-copy-move-files-with-space-at-end-of-file-name) but that's not working, the error I'd get if I add it is: **Illeagal characters in path**.

On the other hand if I use `dir.MoveTo(newName);` without the "\?\" characters I'd get the error: **Could not find a part of the path 'Volunteer Information '**

How can I go through this if at all? would perhaps running this application on linux rather than windows help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote this in a PHP application that's sitting on linux and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For each directory that you want to rename (remove the trailing space at the end in this case), let's say your DirectoryInfo variable is called di

You want to do this:

```
string oldName = di.FullName;
string newName = oldName.TrimEnd();
Directory.Move(oldName, newName);
```

Comment: I tried but I'm getting another error now:
`Source and destination path must be different.`

And if I try to entirely change the path or name of the newName then I get an error saying:
`Could not find a part of the path`

Comment: it probably means that oldName had no trailing space to being with